# Selenium IDE export to Selenium 2

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

Selenium IDE exporting to PHP for Selenium 2 shows errors in simple commands like isElementPresent. How to fix the errors?

This is what I’ve done:

Get Phpunit installed and working 
Running Selenium 2 server-selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar 
Record test case using selenium IDE 2.4.0 
Export the testcase to php file.  (I used this formatter: https://github.com/suzuki/PHP-Formatter-PHPUnit_Selenium2 ) 
Using phpunit to execute the test.

The problem is that the formatter is outputting errors because it can’t find  isElementPresent.
This is the error:

```
ERROR: Caught exception [TypeError: WDAPI.Utils.isElementPresent is not a function]
```

This is the output of the formatter:

```
class Test2 extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
/**
 * Setup
 */
public function setUp()
{
    $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    $this->setHost('127.0.0.1');
    $this->setPort(4444);
    $this->setBrowserUrl('http://mydomain.com/');
}

/**
 * Method test2
 * @test
 */
public function test2()
{
    $this->url("/dvp/index.php?option=com_binja&controller=csinfo&task=loginThenFetchMoreItemsForFranchise&franchiseId=1&itemId=56&poiId=");
    // ERROR: Caught exception [TypeError: WDAPI.Utils.isElementPresent is not a function]
    $this->assertTrue($this->byXPath("//*[@id='authorize']")->displayed());
    $this->byId("binjaEnteredZip")->value("01945");
    $this->byId("btnZipSubmit")->click();
}
}
```

Comment: It seems you have problem with phpunit environment. Try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your function, works for me :)

```
    public function anOtherTest()
    {
        $this->url("/dvp/index.php?option=com_binja&controller=csinfo&task=loginThenFetchMoreItemsForFranchise&franchiseId=1&itemId=56&poiId=");
        // ERROR: Caught exception [TypeError: WDAPI.Utils.isElementPresent is not a function]
        $this->assertTrue($this->byXPath("//*[@id='authorize']")->displayed());
        $this->byId("binjaEnteredZip")->value("01945");
        $this->byId("btnZipSubmit")->click();
    }
```